# VSCode SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org

Tags: salesforcedx

In VSCode working on one module.  I'm trying to make sure I start with the latest source for a module.  When I open a file such as an Apex class, there's a right-mouse menu with SFDX: Delete..., SFDX: Deploy..., SFDX: Diff..., and SFDX: Retrieve....

I tried Deploy and Diff and they work fine.  I try the "SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org" command.  I see it run to success in the OUTPUT tab below.  But the source code in the file isn't updated at all.  I don't get why retrieve doesn't work when diff and deploy do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Working fine for me. Which version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: what does your project manifest look like? do you have all the metadata members you need? Are you looking at a metadata folder that is not a member of your manifest?